Homotopy classes of maps $[S^3/\Gamma, X]$ where $\pi_3(X) = 0$
I'm trying to figure out the homotopy classes of maps $f\colon S^3/\Gamma\to X$ for spaces $X$ where $\pi_3(X) = 0$ and $S^3/\Gamma$ is a spherical space form where $\Gamma\subset\mathrm{SO}(4)$ is a finite group.
I don't really have some concrete strategy to go about this. What I tried was to use a covering map $p\colon S^3\to S^3/\Gamma$ and then to factor $f\colon S^3/\Gamma\to X$ into $F = f\circ p$ for $F\colon S^3\to X$. Then by the assumption $\pi_3(X) = 0$, we know that $F$ is null-homotopic. Thus there is some
\begin{align*}
H\colon S^3\times[0,1]\to X
\end{align*}
such that $H(x, 0) = F(x)$ and $H(x, 1) = p$ for a fixed $p\in X$ and all $x\in S^3$.
Is it possible to then descend this homotopy to define
\begin{align*}
H'\colon S^3/\Gamma\times[0,1]\to X
\end{align*}
by $H'(p(x), s) = H(x,s)$? Hence $[S^3/\Gamma, X]$ is trivial(?)
Are there better/other strategies to tackle this problem?

$[S^3 / \Gamma, X]$ need not be trivial: Take $\Gamma = \mathbb{Z} / 2$ acting by the antipodal map so that $S^3 / \Gamma = \mathbb{R} \mathrm{P}^3$ and consider $[\mathbb{R} \mathrm{P}^3, \mathbb{R} \mathrm{P}^\infty] \cong H^1(\mathbb{R} \mathrm{P}^3; \mathbb{Z} / 2) \cong \mathbb{Z} / 2$.

Hmm yes. Thank you!

You cannot simply descend that homotopy $H$ since $H$ needs to be compatible with the group action to induce a well-defined map on the quotient.

Would you like to include a bit of background info of this problem? I suspect that if we make no additional assumptions on $X$ then the question will be very difficult, e.g. (even in the simplest cases) if I take $X=K(G,1)$ then we get $H^1(S^3/\Gamma;G)$, and if I take $X=K(G,2)$, then we get $H^2(S^3/\Gamma;G)$. These can be non-trivial as Ben's comment shows.

Well... I'd eventually like to find conditions (for the space $X$) such that ${f_*[S^3/\Gamma]\in H_3(X,\mathbb{Z})\mid f\colon S^3/\Gamma\to X}$ becomes trivial. (Yes, one could say $H_3(X,\mathbb{Z}) = 0$ but this is a bit boring.)
